# unexpected behavior when add $setPristine()

Tags: angularjs

There is some unexpected behavior occurring in my project when $setPristine() is added to a function.

Here is a working JSFiddle that demonstrates the behavior:
http://jsfiddle.net/knot22/2x4yt0vb/21/

Here is the HTML:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="formulaCtrlr as vm" >
<form name="vm.formContainer.form" autocomplete="off">
                          <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$invalid}">
                            <label for="FatA" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fat A</label>
                            <input name="FatA" type="text" class="form-control col-sm-10 input-sm" ng-required="true" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" ui-validate="{numberCheck: 'vm.numberCheck($value)', fatRangeCheck: 'vm.fatRangeCheck($value)'}" ng-model="vm.formulaInput.Fats[0]" /><span>%</span>
                            <span class="error" ng-show="vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$invalid">Invalid entry.</span>
                            <span class="error" ng-show="vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$error.numberCheck">{{vm.errorMessages.numberCheck}}</span>
                            <span class="error" ng-show="vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$error.fatRangeCheck">{{vm.errorMessages.fatRangeCheck}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$invalid}">
                            <label for="FatB" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fat B</label>
                                <input name="FatB" type="text" class="form-control col-sm-10 input-sm" ng-required="true" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" ui-validate="{numberCheck: 'vm.numberCheck($value)', fatRangeCheck: 'vm.fatRangeCheck($value)'}" ng-model="vm.formulaInput.Fats[1]" /><span>%</span>
                                <span class="error" ng-show="vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$invalid">Invalid entry.</span>
                                <span class="error" ng-show="vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$error.numberCheck">{{vm.errorMessages.numberCheck}}</span>
                                <span class="error" ng-show="vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$error.fatRangeCheck">{{vm.errorMessages.fatRangeCheck}}</span>
                        </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2">
                                <input type="reset" value="Clear" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.clear()" ng-disabled="vm.formContainer.form.$pristine" />
                            </div>                        
</form>
        <div>formula input: {{vm.formulaInput}}</div>
</div>        
</html>
```

Here is the JS/AngularJS:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.validate'])
    .controller("formulaCtrlr", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            var vm = this;

        vm.formContainer = {
            form: {}
        }

        vm.formulaInput = {};
        vm.formulaInput.Fats = [];

        vm.clear = function () {            
            vm.formulaInput.Fats = [];
            //vm.formContainer.form.$setPristine();
        }

        vm.errorMessages = {
            numberCheck: 'Value must be a number.',
            fatRangeCheck: 'Number must be between 0 and 100.'
        }

        vm.numberCheck = function (value) {
            var result = !(isNaN(parseFloat(value)));
            return result;
            //return !(isNaN(parseFloat(value)));
        }       

        vm.fatRangeCheck = function (value) {
            var result = (value && value > 0.0 && value < 100.0);
            return result;
            //return (value && value > 0.0 && value < 100.0);
        }               

  }]);
```

If the user types abc into the first input box and -20 into the second input box the validation error messages appear, as expected.  When the user clicks the Clear button the input box contents are removed but the validation errors are still displayed.  The goal is to clear out the input boxes and remove the validation error messages when the user clicks Clear.  It seems like adding $setPristine() would achieve this.  However...

To demonstrate the unexpected behavior:

1. enable `//vm.formContainer.form.$setPristine();`
2. click Run
3. type abc into the first input box and -20 into the second input box
4. click Clear button

The validation errors disappear, which is good, but the input boxes still contain abc and -20; this is the unexpected behavior.  Why aren't the input box values being removed?

Comment: (as a workaround: `vm.formulaInput.Fats[0]=null;` could help reseting the values)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey this workaround did the trick when using $setPristine.  In the end I opted for a different approach (see answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to the JSFiddle that now works using $setPristine():
http://jsfiddle.net/knot22/rxqh8jtc/42/

Here is the pertinent part:

```
vm.clear = function () {            
    vm.formulaInput = {};
    vm.formulaInput.Fats = [];
    vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$setPristine();
    vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$setPristine();
}
```